# C++ Linking SQLite to Visual Studio 2019 project

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite with Visual Studio 2019.
I downloaded "amalgamation" package and included"sqlite3.h" and "sqlite3.c" files to the project but I get errors(link to pastebin below)

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlite3.c"
```

https://pastebin.com/6T5HMnyh

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Never include .c files. 2. Never compile .c files with a c++ compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had hit this same thing today.  As S.M. stated, you don't want to include the .c file anywhere in this process.  You should include the sqlite3.h file and follow these instructions.
I found that I not only had to download the amalgmation files but also the dll files (for either x64 or x86 depending on your flavor).
I used https://sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3360000.zip, which gave me a .dll and a .def file.  Copy them to your project directory and then open up a Visual Studio command prompt (terminal in the View menu).  Browse to the directory that you've copied the files to and type `LIB /DEF:sqlite3.def`.  This will create a library file for VS to use.  Add this file to your project dependencies at Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies (you'll have to type it in manually as you can't browse).  Compiling in Visual Studio should now work successfully.

Comment: wow thanks. So, do I have to place these DLL files in Program output folder?(this won't be static linking?)

Comment: Hi @Garlic2394...I have mine in the same directory as the .cpp and .h files and they work fine there.

Comment: Quick update @Garlic2394.  I did find that in order for the executable to run, I did have to move the .dll file into the program output folder.  I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this but it seems to work fine this way.

Comment: No problem @Garlic2394.  If this worked for you, please accept my answer or mark it useful.  Thank you and good luck!

Comment: If you need X64 lib, try:`LIB /DEF:sqlite3.def /MACHINE:X64`